# Custom title and author position

Tags: titles

I'm trying to reproduce http://faculty.kfupm.edu.sa/ME/mqahtani/Publications/21rib.J.Turbo.pdf. I was able to get something similar, but I couldn't use \maketitle, so I had to manually input the title and the authors. Here is my minimum working example:

```
\documentclass[10pt,english]{article}%{asme2e}

\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{verbose,letterpaper,tmargin=0.6in,bmargin=0.6in,lmargin=0.6in,rmargin=0.6in}


\begin{document}

\noindent
\begin{tabu} to \linewidth{X[2,r,m]@{\hspace{10pt}}|[6pt]@{\hspace{10pt}}X[5,l,m]}
\begin{flushright}
{\Large
Author
}\linebreak
{\small
Address \linebreak
Tel
}
\linebreak


{\Large
Author
}\linebreak
{\small
Address \linebreak
Tel
}\linebreak

{\Large
Author
}\linebreak
{\small
Address \linebreak
Tel
}\linebreak

{\Large
Author
}\linebreak
{\small
Address \linebreak
Tel
}
\end{flushright}
&
\begin{flushleft}
\huge
Test with a  long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long title
\end{flushleft}
\justify
{\it
\lipsum[1-2]
}
\end{tabu}
\begin{multicols}{2}

\lipsum[1-10]

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to separate the authors from the title, and still use \author and \title?

Comment: You can always insert all kinds of skips, ex. `\bigskip` and spaces, ex. `\vspace`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This uses `titling`. You still need to specify most of the formatting for the authors simply because you are trying to get addresses etc. in as well. But you can use `\title` as normal. Moreover, it avoids the need for `multicol` which can cause headaches. Put the paragraphs you want typeset as part of the title block in `\myabstract{}` so they get included in `\maketitle`. It is necessary to typeset twice to get things in the right places as the code uses `tikzmark`.

```
\documentclass[10pt,letterpaper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage[margin=0.6in]{geometry}

\usepackage{titling,calc,tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}

\newlength{\bitwidth}
\setlength{\bitwidth}{\textwidth-26pt}
\newlength{\titlewidth}
\setlength{\titlewidth}{5\bitwidth/7}
\newlength{\authorwidth}
\setlength{\authorwidth}{2\bitwidth/7}
\newlength{\normalparindent}
\setlength{\normalparindent}{\parindent}

\pretitle{\begin{minipage}{\titlewidth}\tikzmark{t1}\begin{flushleft}\tikzmark{t2}\huge}
\posttitle{\end{flushleft}\par\vskip 1em\itshape\setlength{\parindent}{\normalparindent}\noindent\artabstract\tikzmark{b}\par\vskip .5em\end{minipage}\par\vskip 1.5em }
\preauthor{\begin{minipage}{\authorwidth}\begin{flushright}\Large}
\postauthor{\end{flushright}\end{minipage}}
\predate{\relax}
\postdate{\relax}
\renewcommand{\maketitlehookb}{\hspace{13pt}\tikzmark{m}\hspace{13pt}}

\newcommand{\artabstract}{\relax}
\newcommand{\myabstract}[1]{\renewcommand{\artabstract}{#1}}

\makeatletter
  \def\@maketitle{% modified from titling.sty
      \newpage%
      \null%
      \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}%
      \vskip 2em%
      \vspace*{\droptitle}%
      \maketitlehooka%
      {\@bspreauthor \@author \@bspostauthor}%
      \maketitlehookb%
      {\@bspretitle \@title \@bsposttitle}%
      \maketitlehookc%
      {\@bspredate \@date \@bspostdate}%
      \maketitlehookd}
\makeatother


\title{Test with a  long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long long title}
\author{Author\\{\small Address\\Tel}\bigskip\\Author\\{\small Address\\Tel}\bigskip\\Author\\{\small Address\\Tel}\bigskip\\Author\\{\small Address\\Tel}}
\date{}
\myabstract{\lipsum[1-2]\par This is just here to avoid the peculiarities in spacing caused by dummy text.}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture, overlay]
  \path [draw, line width=6pt] ($({pic cs:t1} -| {pic cs:m})!1/2!({pic cs:t2} -| {pic cs:m})$) -- ({pic cs:b} -| {pic cs:m});
\end{tikzpicture}
\lipsum[1-4]

\end{document}
```

The `\lipsum[1-4]` gives me a bad box warning. `\lipsum[1-10]` gave me two.

[image: fancy title with titling]

## EDIT

To remove the extra spacing between addresses and telephone numbers, format the authors as follows:

```
\author{Author\\{\small Address\\Tel\bigskip\\}Author\\{\small Address\\Tel\bigskip\\}Author\\{\small Address\\Tel\bigskip\\}Author\\{\small Address\\Tel\\}}
```

[image: fixed author spacing]

Comment: Thank you very much! This is much nicer than what I had done. Just one question: why is there a space between Address and Tel and not between Author and Address?

Comment: @val If this solved your problem, don't forget to accept the answer by clicking on the greyed-out check mark. As well as helping people find solutions by marking the question answered, that gets me reputation and you, as well!